# Replacing long Hypen in SSIS code (Find and Replace)

Tags: sql, ssis

Would like to ask a way to find and replace a long Hypen in my column product title,

Sample Productname:Frozen – Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx

Would like to remove the long hypen before passing it to our final database

Result should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO [Product].[Market].[Products]
([ProductId]
   ,[ProductSourceCd]
,[ProductTitle])
SELECT MP.([ProductId]
   ,MP.[ProductSourceCd]
    CASE MP.[ProductTitle]
WHEN '' THEN REPLACE(ProductTitle," – "," ")
```

Comment: Could you please indicate whether the answer below helped you? If not, please describe why.

Comment: Still doing some test i cant find any change when i use it to replace a hypen.
Also is 8211 a ascii code?

and can i also use replace in a update statement

Comment: No, it's not ascii. That's why it's prefixed with N''

Comment: suggest you post some data

Comment: Frozen – Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx
transform to : Frozen:Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx or Frozen-Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx

Comment: your comment does not make sense.

Comment: thats the data sample.
It the product title

Frozen – Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx
to be transform to Frozen:Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NCHAR(8211)` for en dash, `NCHAR(8212)` for em dash.

```
INSERT INTO Product.Market.Products
(ProductId, ProductSourceCd, ProductTitle)
SELECT MP.ProductId, MP.ProductSourceCd], 
       REPLACE(MP.ProductTitle, N' ' + NCHAR(8211) + N' ',N' ')
FROM
    ...
```

If you are unsure what the character is, convert the unicode character to an integer value:

```
select UNICODE ('–')
```

Comment: as per running the code 
REPLACE(MP.ProductTitle, N' ' + NCHAR(8211) + N' ',N' ')

the hypen is removed and not replace by any character when i try other unicode like ('!') 33 nothing happens

Comment: it do work thanks.

is there a way to do it.i would like to replace the hypen with a simple dash

Comment: replace this Frozen – Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx 
with this
Frozen-Meat xxxx xxxxx xxxx

Comment: Hi All went well my code is now working best regards